# zf create project error (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

I got a error when I try create a project using the zend framework command line:

```
[user ~] /home/user/public_html $ zf create project openstart
```

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Zend_Tool_Framework_Client_Console_ArgumentParser::setArguments() must be an array, null given, called in /home/user/downloads/ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console.php on line 194 and defined in /home/user/downloads/ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console/ArgumentParser.php on line 79
>   
>   **Catchable fatal error**:  Argument 1 passed to Zend_Tool_Framework_Client_Console_ArgumentParser::setArguments() must be an array, null given, called in /home/user/downloads/ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console.php on line 194 and defined in **/home/user/downloads/ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console/ArgumentParser.php** on line **79**

zf is a symlink to /home/user/downloads/ZendFramework-1.10.5/bin/zf.sh

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try a newer version of Zend Framework if possible, they are at 1.11.10 now and I think a number of zend tool issues have been resolved since then.

If I run your command on the newest version I get no errors and the project is created.